# Delegate Func<List<Comment>, Comment, HelperResult> does not take 1 arguments

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

The error is:

```
Delegate Func<List<Comment>, Comment, HelperResult> does not take 1 arguments
```

[image]

While I've given both parameters.How can I fix it?

```
@using Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Helper
@using Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
@model List<Comment>

@{
Func<List<Comment>, Comment, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;
Func<List<Comment>, HelperResult> CreateTree = null;
CreateTree = (Model) => new Func<List<Comment>, HelperResult>(
@<text>@{
    List<Comment> nodesRoot = Model.Where(p => p.ParentId == null).ToList();
    <ul>
        @foreach (var comment in nodesRoot)
        {
            <li>
                <p>@comment.Description</p>

                {

                @ShowTree(Model, comment)

                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
</text>)(null);

ShowTree = (items, parentMenu) => new Func<List<Comment>, Comment, 
HelperResult>(
@<text>@{
<ul>
    @foreach (var comment in items.Where(p => p.ParentId == parentMenu.Id).ToList())
    {
        <li class="">
            <p>@comment.Description</p>
            @if (items.Children(comment).Any())
            {

                @ShowTree(items, comment)

            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
}
</text>)(null, null);
}



<div>
   @CreateTree(Model)
</div>
```

Comment: I have two Delegates. CreateTree with one argument and ShowTree with 2 arguments.

Comment: Wait... nvm.  Might be an invalid error.  your lambdas appear to be invalid.  `CreateTree = (Model) => new Func<List<Comment>, HelperResult>(` isn't correct.  you're returning a func, not a HelperResult.  Try `CreateTree = new Func<List<Comment>, HelperResult>(` or `CreateTree = (Model) => { /* work with Model here */}`.  This is how funcs work:  `Func<A,B> muhFunc = a => new B(A);`, not `Func<A,B> muhFunc = a => new Func<A,B>(new B(A));`

Comment: CreateTree is correct. Only ShowTree has problem. Please look at the picture.

Comment: "Might be an invalid error" can happen in the designer. Do what I said to both, they both look invalid.

Comment: If you can't take my example and adapt it, then I can't help you any further. Good luck.